# To find the missing numbers in a list of cells

Tags: excel

In an excel sheet i have number in A colum.Suppose,in column a the number are as follows:

1

2

3

7

8

11

12

### 13

I need a formula in excel to find out only those numbers which are missing in the list.For example,in the above list,4,5,6,9,10 numbers are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version of the missing numbers formula using Aggregate

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,MIN(A$1:A$10)):INDEX(A:A,MAX(A$1:A$10)))/(COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,ROW(INDEX(A:A,MIN(A$1:A$10)):INDEX(A:A,MAX(A$1:A$10))))=0),ROW()),"")
```

[image]

Comment: ok, but if I have a lot of lines, with numbers and other words, like this. How can I update your formula in order to show me the missing numbers?  See this 
 https://snag.gy/U3ieLG.jpg

Comment: It depends whether the lines are all the same or not - 4-digit number always in same position should be easy, variable number of digits with = before and ; after shouldn't be too bad, but if it's just a number somewhere in a piece of text you might be looking at using VBA with a regex to extract it or at least using a helper column with an array formula..

Comment: I was going to have a look but looks like link has expired?

Comment: all the lines are 4-digit, in this case. I don't know excel, at all. Can you please help me with the right formula in this case? Here is the excel file:  https://jmp.sh/Iqdblhh

Comment: OK well what I did was to insert a new column A (so your data is now in column B) and put in the formula =--MID(B1,17,4). Then just change the formula to =IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,MIN(A$1:A$1090)):INDEX(A:A,MAX(A$1:A$1090)))/(COUNTIF(A$1:A$1090,ROW(INDEX(A:A,MIN(A$1:A$1090)):INDEX(A:A,MAX(A$1:A$1090))))=0),ROW()),"") to fit your 1090 rows of data. The result was that there were no numbers missing. There was something odd about the file, it started repeating after row 1090 with some strange characters. You can also try sorting the data - same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of COUNTIF and IF function.

Assuming the numbers in the list are in columns A1:A8 and the number in question is in B1, type this in a cell:
   IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,$B$1) > 0, "IT EXISTS", "IT DOESN'T EXISTS")

Some References:

[COUNTIF Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

[IF Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69AED7C9-4E8A-4755-A9BC-AA8BBFF73BE2)